# How to run a script only once at a time and get a list of current running scripts?

Tags: php, cron, locking

**Short story:**

I have a script called (`cron_mailings.php`) and I need to know if it is running at the moment. Is there a function or a variable like $_SERVER to get the number of instances of current script (`cron_mailings.php`)?
Because I don't want the script to run more than once at any given moment.

**Long story:**

We have a `cron job` that calls a list of scripts, one of the scripts is (`cron_mailings.php`). 
`cron_mailings.php` goes to `mailings` table, fetches a list of email records -say first 100- then send and delete them from the table. Later the `cron job` will execute again and call`cron_mailings.php` that will process the next 100 emails.

The issue is, someone has wrongly set the cron job whereby last week it ran 6 times in 5 seconds and we had a typical Race Condition, the first instance fetched first 100 user, while it was processing user #10 another instance of the same script was called by the `cron job`, `cron_mailings` ran and fetched 100 users. Now both scripts are overlapping with 90 users who received the same email twice.

We have already fixed the cron job, but just in case I had to find a solution since i don't know who will be playing with that scrip in the future, therefore

**I have implemented two solutions:**

1. Add a field-flag to the db `mailings` table called `is_fetched` (1 for fetched, 0
   otherwise). And set cron_mailings.php to fetch only records marked
   with is_fetched =0. By that solution more than once instance of the
   scrip can actually run and work on different parts of the table
   .e.g. first instance calles first 100 records and assign 1 to
   is_fetched, another instance will come and take the second 100
   records where is_fetched = 0 and work on them.
2. Block the whole script by puting a flag into db table to know if the scrip is running, then at the top of the script something like:

   ```
   check if (is_cron_maillings_running() === 'Y')
   {
       die("script is running at the moment");
   }
   else
   {
       set_is_cron_maillings_running("Y");
       // do some stuff - send emails and save the world
       //1
       //.
       //.
       //10
       set_is_cron_maillings_running("N");
   }
   ```

Both solutions are fine (Basically the second one will overpower the first one)

**But I have an issue:**

What if the script died/crashed/error thrown/db server gone away/ .etc between step 1 and 10 before reaching the last line  `set_is_cron_maillings_running("N");` ? 
Any other scrip called by the cron job will see is_cron_maillings_running = Y in the db table and will never execute again, unless someone manually reassign the value to N.

I'm quite open for suggestions regarding finding a better way locking the script. So far in my opinion, i think if i manage to get a list of running scripts (search if current script is running now) from the server it self, that would be safer than assign values to db tables where scrip could not really fully execute and assign is running = N.

Comment: i had a similar problem, i ended up using this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644323/php-how-to-create-keep-service-in-background-for-consumer

Comment: If you've only got a single machine that runs this script, use a lock file to ensure that only one instance can run at a time. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing Y/N in the lock file/field, store the date when the lock is set (Y), or null for no lock (N).  Then if that date is more than X amount of time ago, ignore it.  This way if something goes wrong, your script will start working again once the lock is stale.

Comment: checking by last lock time, seems good idea.
So every time the scrip actually runs, it will update the time.

Comment: one quick question, let's say the scrip needs 2 min to complete running and being called every 5 min. How long should i set X? 20 min maybe? means after 20 min even if lock = Y  and the script hasn't been called it will override this and run anyway. Good scenario, last script has stopped while lock = Y. Bad scenario last script is still running and that's why lock = Y. So what should i do in this case?

Comment: Guess the only option is to increase time to an amount that guarantee that the script has finished running.

Comment: It's not so much how long you expect it to run most of the time, it's the maximum time it will need.  It might be that most of the time it takes 2 minutes but sometimes due to the nature of the system it takes 30 minutes, in which case a 20 minute stale time would be too short.  So I would look at the maximum expected time period, and how that might change in the future, and then make the stale period longer than that (probably by a factor of between 2 and 5).  It's only when something goes wrong that the lock remains after the process is finished, so you don't have to be too conservative.